Washed my passport by mistake, can that cause a problem?
I washed my passport by mistake, all the necessary information is still there including the first page and the visas.  The problem is that some stamps were erased.  Can that cause a problem?

Google ‘damaged passport + the name of the country that issued it, and you’ll find the official definition. However water damage most likely means you need to replace it

Given that some countries do not allow entry if the passport contains a stamp from some other country, then yes. They need to to see the stamps, and not think they were 'accidentally' erased.

@Traveller It doesn't really matter what the country that issued it thinks - it matters more what every other country you visit thinks!  "Removed" stamps would be considered an invalid passport in most if not all countries.

Argentinian & Spanish passports have RFID chips in them that get damaged with the water - not sure about yours.

@mgarciaisaia damage to RFID chips is not clearly relevant to the usability of a passport, however; passport bearers are (until now, at least) not expected to be able to verify that the chip works and therefore the worst that can happen if it isn't working is that the officer trying to read it can tell you that it isn't working before taking somewhat longer to do whatever it is they're doing (for example, processing the traveler's entry or exit).

@phoog you're right. I remembered some note in my passport about the RFID chip, but after checking it simply suggests not to bend the passport to avoid breaking it - but says nothing about calling it voided.

Let me tell you my experience.
I had to ride my motorbike during heavy rains, with passport in my pocket. The passport itself was not damaged, but the water seeped through and many of the seals were blurred.
I had a flight next day and there was no time to renew. I reached checkin desk and airline refused to let me through. I was traveling to Singapore and I had access to automated gates, which depended only on front page being intact. After much pleading and bargaining, they allowed me to travel, after signing a waiver that its not airline's responsibility if Singapore denies me. Immigration officers also noticed and I promised them I will renew as soon as I land in Singapore.
So, yes, your passport is definitely damaged. Do not attempt to travel with it. Renew it as soon as possible.

One would think that they'd use ink which does not easily dissolve in water?

@PaŭloEbermann I was talking about the stamps placed by immigration of various countries.

Me too. Just to be clear, I don't doubt your experience. It just puzzles me that the border control agencies are using a kind of ink for the stamps which gets dissolved simply by getting the passport wet. (Washing in a washing machine with detergents, as in the question, is another level.)

@PaŭloEbermann it is perhaps puzzling, but the world is a diverse place.

I am a retired UK Border Control Officer.  In my experience if you presented a passport with the damage you have described at most Border controls I am familiar with, it is likely you would routinely be asked to wait whilst further enquiries were made as to the document's probity.  If, ultimately, there was no evidence of fraud or document abuse use you might well be admitted to the country but your journey would obviously be delayed by an hour or two. Every time you travelled. Probably not what you want?
Use your common sense. Apply for a replacement document. Straight away.

(+1) That's because UKBF cares about getting it right. Less sophisticated countries, especially more authoritarian ones, will simply send you back at the slightest smell that something's off.

I wonder if you are trained that way.

@Crazydre "less sophisticated", really? And I can assure you that while the border agents in large UK airports have been very helpful and knowledgeable in my experience, those in smaller, provincial airports are not immune to the pettiness that characterizes small minds given a tiny bit of power. I have no doubt those are exceptions, but having met one of those exceptions multiple times, I would urge you not to believe the UK is in any way special.

The lack of stamps can cause a problem, at least with the authorities of any country that placed a missing stamp.  They may have a record of placing the stamp, in which case there could be a problem if they see the passport without seeing the stamp.
If there is a faint ink stain where any stamp used to be, almost any official could conclude that the passport has been altered, which could lead to their rejecting the passport.  Indeed, the appearance of general water damage -- that the paper was soaked and has dried with waves or wrinkles in it -- would likely at least raise enough suspicion that the officer would examine the passport closely.  Any sign of alteration could cause them to consider the passport invalid, even if they believe you when you tell them how the passport was altered and that it was unintentional.
The safest course of action is to replace the passport.

Of course, it seems you have destroyed your passport and made the it partially or completely unusable. AFAIK washing removes/affects the layer on the first page. Do you still have shininess on the first pages and visa stickers? It’s better to get a new one. On a regular trip(except some occasions), your passport undergoes scanners/readers multiple times. You can’t travel with an unusable passport that machines can’t read.

The final sentence of your answer is true, but isn't responsive: the OP does not say that their passport's MRZ is unreadable.

What layer on the first page?  I have two passports; the first page of one of them is a plastic card with no layer of anything and the first page of the other is paper, but coated with water-insoluble plastic.

I acquired some water damage on my passport in Bahrain. (no missing stamps and the photo page is plastic on the passport, but it did have wrinkled pages)
I  could use it to return to South Africa (this was in 2019), but it was viewed with suspicion. I immediately replaced it when I got back. (there is no consulate in Bahrain, so replacing it there would not be easy - getting to a consulate requires crossing international borders)
It might have helped that I was returning to my country of citizenship - trying to travel outbound might be a lot more problematic (and riskier for the airlines).
In short: Replace it ASAP, ideally before using it at all...

A few years ago, I put my passport through the washing machine (in my jeans pocket). The pages were all warped, but the ink was mostly not smudged. The only exception to this was my handwritten signature on the back page.
Since when I did this I had a flight coming up in the next week or so, I visited a nearby airport and asked them if they thought it would be acceptable. They couldn't say, so I just risked it. It worked fine, and border control people never seem to give it a second look.
